# haProxy : Limiting the payload / data length in bytes

Tags: haproxy

I am using haProxy to distribute webSockets through 4 local websocket servers.

Is it possible to reject data (or close connection preferably) if the payload / data length being sent to server, is over 512 bytes ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create an acl with "req.len" in order to do this.